# Can 'UNION ALL' be used with 'INSERT INTO' in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can I write something like this in postgres 9.4?

```
SELECT id FROM image_instance WHERE name = 'bioboxes/velvet-then-quast'

UNION ALL

INSERT INTO image_instance (name, sha256, image_type_id)
SELECT
    'bioboxes/velvet-then-quast',
    'digest_4',
    (SELECT id FROM image_type WHERE name = 'short_read_preprocessing_reference_evaluation')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM image_instance WHERE name = 'bioboxes/velvet-then-quast')
RETURNING id
```

I get a syntax error on the `INSERT` so I assume this is not possible? I thought it worth asking in case I am writing this incorrectly.

I know that this is not thread safe, however this is for a single threaded application.

Comment: You you tried it in the format  INSERT INTO ...   SELECT .... UNION ALL   SELECT ...  ?  Also the number of fields in your selects must be equal to the number of fields you are inserting.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried swapping the top and bottom clauses but then I get a syntax error on UNION

Comment: That is probably due to your first select only having one field and your second three fields.  They both have to have the same number as the insert (three).  Try just getting your SELECT UNION ALL SELECT going first, then when that is fine, then add your INSERT to the top

Comment: @Dijkgraaf As far as I can tell from running each clause separately they both return a single field 'id'

Comment: So why does your insert have 3 fields?

Comment: The 'RETURNING id' part returns only the 'id' field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101833/discussion-between-dijkgraaf-and-michael-barton).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are after this. Just wrap your `INSERT` into a CTE (use WITH):

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    INSERT INTO image_instance (name, sha256, image_type_id)
    SELECT
        'bioboxes/velvet-then-quast',
        'digest_4',
        (SELECT id FROM image_type WHERE name = 'short_read_preprocessing_reference_evaluation')
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM image_instance WHERE name = 'bioboxes/velvet-then-quast')
    RETURNING id
)
SELECT id FROM image_instance WHERE name = 'bioboxes/velvet-then-quast'
UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM CTE
;
```

This query would insert some rows into `image_instance`; the generated values of `id` column would be returned by `RETURNING` clause; which in their turn would be `UNIONed ALL` with (previous?) values of `id` from `image_instance`.

I'm not sure what the result would be, you should check, but the syntax should be correct.

Comment: Thanks for this Vladimir. I am using a CTE already but I wondered if there was a way to simplify it any further using a UNION ALL, however it does not appear to be possible.

Comment: You'd better explain what you are trying to achieve, what's your ultimate goal, rather than focusing on the syntax. The query in the answer may have correct syntax, but it doesn't make much sense to me.